# extracting a specific link pattern using java pattern matcher

Tags: java, regex

Let's say I have a link like below along with a bunch of other links

```
http://testttt.com/met?tag1=x&tag2=y&tag3=z%20a
```

I would like to extract the entire link if it starts with http://testttt.com/met

I tried doing the following but it didn't work

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("http://testttt.com/met?[a-zA-Z][0-9]");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher("http://testttt.com/met?tag1=x&tag2=y&tag3=z%20a");
if (match.find()) {
   System.out.println("match found");
}
```

Comment: you should read something about regular expressions. [a-zA-Z] matches a SINGLE letter. you probably mean this [a-z]* which matches zero or more letters.

Comment: What is the surrounding text?  Are there delimiters in play?  Are the links one per line?  Is this link within an anchor?  It's often easier to put out links if you know what follows that is NOT part of the link, like a quote, double quote, etc.

Comment: "I would like to extract the entire link if it starts with http://testttt.com/met" are u trying to extract the url or the params?

Comment: @sailingthoms : I would like to extract the entire URL along with parameters.

Comment: so I would recommend Reimeus' answer.

Comment: @reimeus : it worked. I don't understand why i didn't think about it :D

Comment: @user1669488 Its easy to forget those handy String methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use

```
if (str.startsWith("http://testttt.com/met")) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string only contains the url, use the answer proposed by Reimeus. If you're trying to extract the url from a bunch of text, you can use this pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("http://testttt\\.com/met\\??[^\\s]*");
```

It contains all the necessary escapes and and matches everything up to the next whitespace.